Haproxy configuratin error - Redirected you too many times
I've been diligently working on configuring HAProxy to properly redirect traffic to the appropriate server, but despite several days of effort, I'm still encountering issues.
My setup involves a virtual machine running HAProxy, with a NAT rule in place to direct all incoming traffic from my modem to the HAProxy instance. The goal is to enable access to my Plex server from the public internet by typing in "plex.MY_DOMAIN.com". However, when attempting to access it via a browser, I'm encountering an error:
This page isn’t working
plex.MY_DOMAIN.com redirected you too many times.
Below, I've provided my configuration. Could someone please lend their expertise and assist me in resolving this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated.
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http_front
    bind 10.0.0.13:443 ssl crt /home/dental/proxy/MY_DOMAIN.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    mode http
    timeout client 30s

    acl is_plex hdr(host) -i plex.MY_DOMAIN.com
    acl is_nas hdr(host) -i nas.MY_DOMAIN.com
    acl is_proxmox hdr(host) -i proxmox.MY_DOMAIN.com

    acl root_dir path -i /

    http-request redirect location https://plex.MY_DOMAIN.com/web/index.html if is_plex !{ hdr_cnt(X-Plex-Device-Name) gt 0 } root_dir

    use_backend plex_backend if is_plex
    use_backend nas_backend if is_nas
    use_backend proxmox_backend if is_proxmox
    default_backend default_backend

backend plex_backend
    mode http
    timeout server 30s
    server plex_server 10.0.0.14:32400

backend nas_backend
    mode http
    timeout server 30s
    server nas_server 10.0.0.14

backend proxmox_backend
    mode http
    timeout server 30s
    server proxmox_server 10.0.0.10:8006

backend default_backend
    mode http
    timeout server 30s
    http-request deny

Thank you in advance.
